# Restricting class to one instance without using singleton?

Tags: java, singleton

I don't want to use singleton, but I simply cannot allow more than one instance of my class.

Would you consider this a good approach, and if not, what's a better way?

```
public class SoundSystem {

    private static boolean instanceCreated = false;

    public SoundSystem() {
        if(instanceCreated) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Only one instance can be created.");
        }

        instanceCreated = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to use singleton, but you want a singleton.  How about you say why you don't want to use singleton, and what you mean by that?

Comment: Well, I've read in many places that singleton is a code smell, and I have to agree that it isn't very pretty. I only want to restrict number of instances.

Comment: This *is* a singleton, even if you're not representing it with more traditional notation. In any case, your logic is reasonable although not thread-safe. More importantly, this seems like a bit of a code smell. Can you tell us why do you actually want to do this? Be careful not to fall into the trap of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The point is that the SoundSystem initializes some OpenAL stuffs and I can't allow it to be done twice.

Comment: "I only want to restrict number of instances." When the number is one, this is the very definition of a singleton. Even if you do it in your own special way, if you're restricting the number of instances, and that number happens to be one, it's a singleton.

Comment: @MightyPork So why not create one instance of your class when your program starts (don't bother with the whole singleton enforcement) and pass that instance you created to objects that use it? On top of that, you can let OpenAL take care of reporting any multiple initialization errors. As a bonus, this also lets you easily drop in support for different types of `SoundSystem`s if you need it some day.

Comment: Oh, so you want a Singleton? Although it sounds more like you only want to run a method once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *is* a singleton, even if you are not enforcing it in the "traditional" manner. I don't recommend this approach, and I think you should find another way.

For example, why not create a single `SoundSystem` instance when your program starts? You don't need to explicitly enforce its single-ness, just pass that instance along to other objects that need access to the sound system. As a bonus, this also lets you easily drop in support for different types of `SoundSystem`s if you need it some day (a nice little extra benefit, even if you don't need this).

On top of all this, will the OpanAL initialization itself fail if you try and initialize multiple `SoundSystem`s? If not, then there's not really a reason to place an artificial limit. If so, then you can just let OpanAL determine what is and isn't an error. But in any case, it wouldn't be a risk if you simply just create one instance and pass it off instead of letting all your application classes query the instance themselves.

Be careful you don't fall into the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) trap here. Singletons aren't *inherently* evil, but for some reason they are *frequently* misused, hence the general advice against them. There is usually a cleaner way, and these cleaner ways usually come with a lot of bonus added benefit. Think about the *actual* problem you are trying to solve / situation you are trying to avoid here.

Comment: Well, what's your opinion on doing the initialization in a static block? It seems like a good way, unless it's got some drawbacks I'm not aware of.

Comment: @MightyPork Same opinion! In a multi-threaded environment a static block is a thread-safe approach, if a singleton must be used. In a single-threaded environment it's essentially just a synonym for what you are already doing. Refactoring your code to provide the same functionality in a static block just expresses the same conceptual design in a different way. So my opinion is the same; singletons are singletons no matter how you enforce them. You asked about a "good approach" so you seemed interested in conceptual design approaches; the static block is basically the same approach you have now.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll go with that.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a good approach.

Let's take a quick example in a context of multi-threading.

Thread 1 instantiates `SoundSystem`, the `if(instanceCreated)` returns false, before changing `instanceCreated` to true the scheduler interrupts Thread 1. Now Thread 2 can also instantiates `SoundSystem` since `isInstanceCreated` is false at that time.

But at the end, both thread will have a different instance.

Comment: Yeah, that's actually the case, but I think I'll in the end stick to a static block, thus avoiding those problems altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an enum, if you are willing to make all of your fields `final`. This too has some "code smell" to it though. It will protect against multi-threaded issues, but does have the restriction that all of your `SoundSystem` instance variables would need to be final.

```
public enum SoundSystem {
    INSTANCE("Hello", "World");

    private final Object field1;
    private final Object field2;

    private SoundSystem(Object field1, Object field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return field1.toString() + "  " + field2.toString();
    }

    public Object getField1() {
        return this.field1;
    }

    public Object getField2() { 
        return this.field2;
    }

    //etc., etc.
}
```

You can then use `SoundSystem.INSTANCE` to gain access to your singleton item

Comment: I'm trying to avoid code smell here, not aiming to introduce another, even worse.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you posted allows a garden variety "race-condition". Two entities trying to create a your SoundSystem at the same time could end up both creating an instance.

Maybe making all the methods of and variables of SoundSystem static will get you what you desire, but it is hard to know without more information.

Comment: It would be nice to have a comment as to why this answer was down-voted. I'm here to learn.

Comment: Making it all static is out of question, for I need it to implement certain interfaces.. but you've got a point with the race condition.